# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7, Kotlin, Gradle - bean couldn't be found

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I've trying to run a small Spring Boot application that was writing in Kotlin and built with Gradle. When I run the application in IntelliJ I receive the following message:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of constructor in com.mycompany.app.rest.api.MyApi
>   required a bean of type 'com.mycompany.app.domain.UserRepository' that
>   could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.mycompany.app.domain.UserRepository' in your configuration.

MyAPP:

[MyAPP directory structure and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q42Fj.png)


Myapp.kt

```
package com.mycompany.app.startbootapp

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = arrayOf("com.mycompany.app"))
class MyApp

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runApplication<MyApp>(*args)
    }
```

MyApi.kt

```
package com.mycompany.app.rest.api

import com.mycompany.app.domain.User
import com.mycompany.app.domain.UserRepository
import com.mycompany.app.infra.ParamUtil
import com.mycompany.app.rest.api.inout.DtoUser
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@RestController
class MyApi(val paramUtil: ParamUtil, val repo: UserRepository) {


    @PostMapping("/user")
    fun tokenJwtUsuario(@RequestBody dto: DtoUser, request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse):
            ResponseEntity<String> {
        if (!paramUtil.verificaParam(dto.id) && !paramUtil.verificaParam(dto.name)) {
            return ResponseEntity("Invalid parameter provided !", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        }
        var user = User(dto.id, dto.name)
        repo.save(user)
        return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)

    }
}
```

User.kt

```
package com.mycompany.app.domain

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
data class User(

        @Id
        val userID: String,
        val name: String
) { }
```

UserRepository.kt

```
package com.mycompany.app.domain

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
interface UserRepository: JpaRepository<User, String> {
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.10'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.mycompany'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.10")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
}
```

I tried to move the MyApp.kt to the above directory in com.mycompany.app but without success.

Comment: Move main class to package `com.mycompany.app` and it should start working.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I've tried this, but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` to your `MyApp`-Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = arrayOf("com.mycompany.app"))
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = arrayOf("com.mycompany.app.domain"))
@EntityScan(value = "com.mycompany.app.domain")
class MyApp
```

Comment: Thank you Rene. It works for me. I was looking for Spring Boot documentation and it is not clear about the obligation of this setting @EnableJpaRepositories. Session 77.3 Use Spring Data repositories in docs.

Comment: @etc If this answer helped you, please accept the answer, that will help fellow SOers too.